# How to convert a Time value inside a string from PT Format to Seconds?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column: `runtime` in my json file that contains a String whose data is in PT format.
Ex:

```
{ "day":"Monday","runtime":"PT45M"},
{ "day":"Tuesday","runtime":"PT1H"},
{ "day":"Wednesday","runtime":"PT4H5S"},
{ "day":"Thursday","runtime":"PT2H1M"},
{ "day":"Friday","runtime":"PT2M1S"}
```

When I loaded the above file into my local myql table, it was inferred as String type by Spark.

```
>>> df.select('runtime').show()
+--------+
| runtime|
+--------+
|   PT45M|
|   PT20M|
|   PT15M|
|    PT1H|
|   PT45M|
|   PT30M|
|   PT15M|
|   PT30M|
|    PT1H|
|   PT20M|
|   PT45M|
|   PT30M|
```

Now I am trying to convert the value of column `runtime` in PT format to Seconds.

In plain Python, I was able to parse the value from a PT format string and get the value from it.
Ex:

```
>>> txt = 'PT20M'
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)M", txt).group(1)) * 60)
1200
>>>
>>> txt = 'PT1H'
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)H", txt).group(1)) * 60 * 60)
3600
>>>
>>> txt = 'PT20S'
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)S", txt).group(1)))
20
>>>
```

Then there are strings with (Hours-Minutes), (Hours-Seconds), (Minutes-Seconds).
For the strings with two types, the second value can be accessed via `group(2)`.

Example:

```
>>> txt = 'PT1H2M'
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)H(\d+)M", txt).group(1)))
1
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)H(\d+)M", txt).group(2)))
2
>>> txt = 'PT5M34S'
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)M(\d+)S", txt).group(1)))
5
>>> print(int(re.search(r"(\d+)M(\d+)S", txt).group(2)))
34
>>>
```

Is there a way to apply the regex on my dataframe's `runtime` column when there is a combination of two types as mentioned above and convert its value into Seconds in a new column.

I tried starting with string of type HOUR and faced error like below:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('matched',F.when(df.runtime.rlike('(\d+)H'), int(re.search(r"(\d+)H", df.col('runtime')).group(1))*60*60).otherwise(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1643, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
>>>
```

I couldn't think of a way to apply this regex on the column: `runtime` and then convert them to seconds into a new column.
Could anyone let me know how can I achieve the solution ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the hour/minute/second part of the runtime column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'runtime', 
    F.coalesce(F.regexp_extract('runtime', r'(\d+)H', 1).cast('int'), F.lit(0)) * 3600 + 
    F.coalesce(F.regexp_extract('runtime', r'(\d+)M', 1).cast('int'), F.lit(0)) * 60 + 
    F.coalesce(F.regexp_extract('runtime', r'(\d+)S', 1).cast('int'), F.lit(0))
)

df2.show()
+---------+-------+
|      day|runtime|
+---------+-------+
|   Monday|   2700|
|  Tuesday|   3600|
|Wednesday|  14405|
| Thursday|   7260|
|   Friday|    121|
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: How should I apply when there are two types in the input? For example I have PT2H4M, How can I parse this? Thats the real problem..

Comment: this solution should work. If you look at the row for Thursday, 2H1M was correctly parsed to be 7260 seconds.